# Why we use -i or --interactive in the Node.js?

Tags: node.js

Why we use `-i` or `--interactive` in Node.js if we can easily jump into the REPL with just a simple command `node` ?

I have read the documentation but the documentation is a little bit confusing:

[Reference Link](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_i_interactive)

> Opens the REPL even if stdin does not appear to be a terminal.

I understand the part `Opens the REPL` but didn't understand what does `even if stdin does not appear to be a terminal` mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When executing `node` in a text terminal by itself, the program will provide a REPL for interactive use by a human. However, it might be the case that `node` is not run in a terminal, or that it was given a script to execute in a non-interactive fashion, which makes `node` run the given script without providing a REPL. For example, this would likely be the case for a Node.js [child process](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/child_process.html) which is given input and output streams between the parent process and the child process. As another example, the command below will not execute `node` in interactive mode:

```sh
echo "console.log('Hello');" | node
```

The `-i` option is designed to override this automatic decision, by forcing `node` to provide a REPL regardless of whether it has detected the presence of a text terminal. This may be particularly useful for making non-user-facing programs which streamline the REPL's inputs and outputs to another application.

---

Node.js itself provides an additional layer on top of input and output streams for those which are associated with a text terminal. According to the [TTY](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/tty.html#tty_tty) module:

> When Node.js detects that it is being run with a text terminal ("TTY") attached, `process.stdin` will, by default, be initialized as an instance of `tty.ReadStream` and both `process.stdout` and `process.stderr` will, by default be instances of `tty.WriteStream`.

If you run `node` and type in `process.stdin.isTTY`, it will output `true`. The following command, on the other hand, will print `undefined`:

```sh
echo "console.log(process.stdin.isTTY)" | node
```